# Branch with condition (BXNE !?)

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

The following code is machine generated asm of a loop.

```
0x98548 <+200>: sub.w  r0, r7, #0xe
0x9854c <+204>: ldr    r1, [sp, #0x8]
0x9854e <+206>: add    r0, r1
0x98550 <+208>: str    r0, [sp, #0x4]
0x98552 <+210>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x8]
0x98554 <+212>: adds   r0, #0x1
0x98556 <+214>: str    r0, [sp, #0x8]
0x98558 <+216>: ldr    r0, [sp, #0x4]
0x9855a <+218>: sub.w  r1, r7, #0x35
0x9855e <+222>: blx    0x9bfec                   ; symbol stub for: strcmp
0x98562 <+226>: cmp    r0, #0x0
0x98564 <+228>: bne    0x98548
```

At `0x98564 <+228>: bne    0x98548`, is it possible to replace this line with a branch to a location in register, like below:
`bxne r6`, where `r6` holds the value of `0x98548`?

Comment: What happened when you tried? What is the actual problem?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It works with armv7, but not work with arm thumb.

Comment: Yes, only `BX` is available in thumb mode, `BXNE` is not. In thumb you could probably use `IT` to do it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen If OP is using unified syntax (which he is), the assembler should automatically replace `BXNE` with an `IT` and `BX`.

Answer (score 0):

How did you know the OP was using unified syntax?  I see disassembly there

```
.syntax unified
.thumb
nop
nop
bxne r0
nop
nop
nop
skip:
nop
nop
nop
```

with the .thumb

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:6: Error: thumb conditional instruction should be in IT block -- `bxne r0'
```

without

```
00000000 <skip-0x18>:
   0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   112fff10    bxne    r0
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  14:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)

00000018 <skip>:
  18:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  1c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  20:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
```

with .thumb and -mcpu=cortex-m0 on the command line still produces the assembler error.  It is not generating an IT block.

without unified syntax

```
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:5: Error: Thumb does not support conditional execution
```

ARM instructions have four bits for conditionals on every instruction (aarch32), thumb do not you cannot conditional everything including bx.  You have to use the IT block or use normal conditional branches to branch to or around the bx if you even need the bx (are you switching modes between arm/thumb).